# Main: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, list, program-entry-point

I am making list and want to look at it in console. I have one error, It says:

> Main(): not all code paths return a value.

Maybe you could help me? Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class DocConfig
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<DocPart> Parts { get; set; }
​
        public class DocPart
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string TexLine { get; set; }

            public class Program
            {
                public static int Main()
                {
                    List<DocPart> Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                    var doc = new DocConfig();
                    doc.Description = "bla bla";
                    doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                    doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
                    doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
                    foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
                        {
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your doc.Parts is empty,you will miss your return 0.Add anything in the last line of the method code

Comment: Off-topic but is there a reason you need nested classes? ... it looks like it is already getting messy

Comment: yes, I will need them in future use

Comment: @Mantas: You *need* them to be nested classes? That sounds unlikely...

Comment: If the method signature says it will return something, it has to do it in all conditions. If your list is empty, method will not return anything. So, you might return a default value at the end of the method, which will fix the compile error. Also, notice that, you are returning in a loop. So, in the first iteration itself the method will return, and the rest of the loop will not be executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# returning error "not all code paths return a value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-returning-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return something at the end of `Main`. Like this:

```
public static int Main()
{
     List<DocPart> Parts = new List<DocPart>();
     var doc = new DocConfig();
     doc.Description = "bla bla";
     doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
     doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
     doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
     foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
     {
           Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
           {
                 Console.ReadLine();
                 return 0;
           }
     }

     return -1;
}
```

Comment: It says now, that return is class,struct or interface member declaration. Invalid token

Comment: @Mantas ... It is because closing curly braces. Check where are you placed ` return -1;`

Comment: @Mantas...Make sure that you have placed ` return -1;` just before the end of the `Main` method. Also check you don't have extra closing curly braces.

Comment: Thank you!!! but still it show 1more error in line 12 invalid token " but there is empty row. what is this?

Comment: @Mantas...Rebuild your solution once also verify again for extra closing curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting this error is because when you declared the method

```
public static int Main()
```

you declared it would return an `int` value. However, you only return that value in a place which might never be run. For instance, it would never be run if the `doc.Parts` list were to be empty. So, you need to add code that makes sure the method always returns something.

Adding `return -1;` in the end of the method, for example, would make the error go away in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int Main()
            {
                List<DocPart> Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                var doc = new DocConfig();
                doc.Description = "bla bla";
                doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
                doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
                foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
                    {
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Add some explanation please.