# How to add more items to my list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have created list. And it compiles and shows only one item. I need to make it show all my inserted items. For example I try insert one more. How should i do that?

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class DocConfig
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<DocPart> Parts;

        public class DocPart
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string TexLine { get; set; }

            public class Program
            {
                public static int Main()
                {

                    List<DocPart> Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                    var doc = new DocConfig();
                    doc.Description = "bla bla";
                    doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
                    doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
                    doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb ", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });

                    foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `return 0`

Comment: And why Main method should return any number ?

Comment: Although your program is short, you should also try to narrow down the snippets of code you include in your question to just the shortest necessary code needed, in this case that would have been the `Main` method on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is only showing one is because your loop over parts is returning from the method and therefore it never gets chance to complete any other iterations.

The solution is to not return early (Remove the `return 0;`) from this method and instead let it run to the end.

Some other changes I made below were:

- Removed the read keys from the for loop. You probably don't want the user to have to press a key every iteration either.
- Un-nested classes. Your nested classes also seemed wierd to me and will just lead you to messy code.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class DocConfig
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<DocPart> Parts;
    }

    public class DocPart
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TexLine { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main()
        {

            List<DocPart> Parts = new List<DocPart>();
            var doc = new DocConfig();
            doc.Description = "bla bla";
            doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb ", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });

            foreach (DocPart part in doc.Parts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: return -1 seems more wierd than nested class to me, thats probably useless. I think the OP had copy paste code so he dont really know what is happening.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - That was suggested to the OP in [their last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33689821/1324033), so I didn't want to confuse them with conflicting answers. I agree returning 0 is probably better here