# c# public static string, not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, string, return

I dont understand methods fully yet, and i dont know why is this happening... Im trying to make my code change ints to words, and i think this is the way to go.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Hi wanna play rock paper scissors?<press enter to continue>");
            Console.ReadKey();
            int user = 0;
            int ai = r.Next(1, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("Pick what youll show! (1-rock, 2-paper, 3-scissors) and press enter");
            user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (user > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR! your number must be <= 3. <Press enter to close the program>");
                goto end;
            }
            if (user == ai)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Its a draw! <press enter to continue>");
                goto end;
            }


            Console.WriteLine(user);

end:
Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string ntw (int user) //ntw: not all code paths return a value
    {
        if (user == 1)
            return "rock";
        if (user == 2)
            return "paper";
        if (user == 3)
            return "scissors";

    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if `user` isn't 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: 1. Please don't use `goto`. 2 Please double check your indentation for consistency and readability when posting code.

Comment: You should really use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) for this kinda thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main: not all code paths return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689768/main-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 9):

Your method's return type is `string`. That means your method should always return some string value. With your current implementation it is returning some string when the value of user variable is `1` or `2` or `3`. What if you call this method with value `25` ? The compiler does not know what to do!

Your method should return some string if the user value is not `1` or `2` or `3`

```
public static string ntw (int user)
{
     if (user == 1)
        return "rock";
     if (user == 2)
         return "paper";
     if (user == 3)
         return "scissors";

     return string.empty; // Here i am returning an empty string.
}
```

Comment: Or return string.empty :).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a switch statement, in this case the default would give u a Null or an empty string if the user isn't 1, 2 or 3 :)

```
    public static string ntw (int user)
    {
        switch (user)
        {
            case 1:
                return "rock";
            case 2:
                return "paper";
            case 3:
                return "scissors";
            default:
                return null; // or return string.Empty
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values must be in range 1..3 (and returning the `string.Empty` string has no sense) then you can write:

```
public static string ntw (int user) 
{
    if (user == 1)
        return "rock";
    if (user == 2)
        return "paper";
    if (user == 3)
        return "scissors";
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid choice");
}
```

and handle the exception somewhere in the program.