# Not all code paths Return a Value : Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have a Section of code that is compiling with the error of

> "Not all code paths Return a Value"

I have no idea how to fix this. Any Ideas? Here is my code.

```
bool EnemyIsAlive()
{
    searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
    {
        searchCountdown = 1f;
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# returning error "not all code paths return a value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-returning-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

The `EnemyIsAlive()` should return a boolean value for all possible conditions; in your case; The method will not return anything if `if (searchCountdown <= 0f)` evaluates to `false`. So you need to add  a return statement for the false condition. It may `true/false` according to the scenario you are dealing with, but a return should be there.

```
bool EnemyIsAlive()
{
    searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
    {
        searchCountdown = 1f;
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
  return false; // one line added to solve the error
}
```