# FizzBuzz test case pass

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

I am wondering can someone please tell me where I am going wrong with this FizzBuzz.

I get an error "not all code returns a value and struggling to find out exactly how to fix it.

My code is below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
    }
    else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

**And the test case is this:**

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var solution = new Solution();

    Assert.AreEqual(solution.PrintFizzBuzz(15), "FizzBuzz");    
}
```

Comment: please provide the whole function you are testing - not just the body

Comment: I think you need to return a string from the `PrintFizzBuzz` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# returning error "not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-returning-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: Side note: you'll get `FizzBuzz` for `0` and stop one number before `input`/

Comment: @ZoharPeled Are you sure? I'd say he will _never_ get "FizzBuzz": https://dotnetfiddle.net/eCifvZ

Comment: @Fildor correct. He will get `Fizz`.

Comment: Just for fun - a one liner FizzBuzz: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Enumerable.Range(1, input).Select(i => (i % 15 == 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : (i % 5 == 0) ? "Buzz" : (i % 3 == 0) ? "Fizz" : i.ToString())));`

Comment: This was all the code I was given was the test case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of like other people have said, not all the code is present so it's difficult for us to help. But I'll try anyway.

When testing with `Assert.AreEqual` the function `PrintFizzBuzz` should return something, in this case the string "FizzBuzz". But if you are using the `Console.WriteLine` method it will return nothing. The `Console.Writeline` method will print the string to the console, but the console is not actually the 'program', it's just for visualising some things like logging or debugging.

So to fix your issue you should use `return` instead of `Console.Writeline` and let your method `PrintFizzBuzz` return a string instead of voiding and printing it to the console. It's probably also better to rename your method in this case, because it doesn't print FizzBuzz anymore.

Your code has also another issue and that's when you input 15 it will print out "Fizz", because the check you do is modulo 3 and 15 % 3 = 0. You should order your check the otherway around, from specific to less specific.

An example for returning a string would be:

```
string SomeMethod()
{
    return "Some String"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see where I went wrong there now, thanks for the explaination regarding why I won't get FizzBuzz

Answer (score 4):

> not all code returns a value

Means your method declared having a return type and not `void` but you are not returning anything from your method. One example case:

```
int Add(int a, int b)
{
  int c = a + b;
  // no return specified would through the same error
}
```