# How to return the variable "string" from the "switch"?

Tags: c#

How to return the variable "string" from the "switch"?

There is a method

```
public string ParsingAll(int i, string cssSelector, string attr) 
{
  try
  {
    string str1 = "def";
    switch (i)
    {
      case 0: 
        var items = document.QuerySelectorAll(cssSelector); 

        str1 = items[0].TextContent.Trim();

        break;
    }
        return str1;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string s = ex.Message;    
  }
}
```

I get the error
 *"not all branches of code return value"*

How to return the variable "string" from the "switch"?

Comment: The catch block doesn't return anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# returning error "not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-returning-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in catch block.

Generally, I would prefer a return null statement out of all try catch blocks to avoid these issues.

```
public string ParsingAll(int i, string cssSelector, string attr) 
{
  try
  {
    string str1 = "def";
    switch (i)
    {
      case 0: 
        var items = document.QuerySelectorAll(cssSelector); 

        str1 = items[0].TextContent.Trim();

        break;
    }
        return str1;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string s = ex.Message;    
    throw ;/// OR handle exception, log it, etc based on your requirements.
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a return to your catch (or after it that would cover all branches by itself):

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    string s = ex.Message;    
  }

return null;  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your catch does not return anything, but the `ParsingAll` method requires you to return a string.

You could return null as suggested by [@uɐʞɥsɐ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079221/u%C9%90%CA%9E%C9%A5s%C9%90) or throw an exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string s = ex.Message;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: i'm amazed that you went all the way and copy pasted this guy's backwards name.

Comment: Lol. There you go, there's a link now.