# I don't know how to fix this cs0161 error in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I keep getting this error, and I don't know how to fix it:

> CS0161:Home.Controller.Index(): not all code paths return a value

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TipCalculator.Models;

namespace TipCalculator.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()      // the Index is underline in red
        {
            ViewBag.Fifteen = 0;
            ViewBag.Twenty = 0;
            ViewBag.TwentyFive = 0;     
            View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Calculator calc)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Fifteen = calc.CalculateTip(0.15);
                ViewBag.Twenty = calc.CalculateTip(0.20);
                ViewBag.TwentyFive = calc.CalculateTip(0.25);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Fifteen = 0;
                ViewBag.Twenty = 0;
                ViewBag.TwentyFive = 0;
            }

            return View(calc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *return* View(), as in your other method

Comment: did you notice that you are missing a `return` before calling `View()`?

Comment: the `Index` method should return the view like this `return View()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# compiler error: "not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-compiler-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 3):

> **CS0161:Home.Controller.Index(): not all code paths return a value

To help you understand this message. Above error message means `Index()` method in `HomeController` does not return a value. Looking at `Index()` method I see return statement is missing. Add a return statement to `Index()` method to eliminate this error. Replace you index method with following method. This is exact copy of your method but with last statement `View();` replaced with `return View();`.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()      // the Index is underline in red
{
    ViewBag.Fifteen = 0;
    ViewBag.Twenty = 0;
    ViewBag.TwentyFive = 0;     
    return View();
}
```