# Revit Addin Template2020

Tags: revit-api, autodesk

I used the Revit Add-In Template but when I run the application I get this error. Do you know why I am getting this error?
the error I get is Revit cannot run ExternalApplication.
do you know why it cannot run the External Application?

`The Error Message`

```
External Tools- External Tool Failure = Revit Cannot run External application "Application NewRibbon01"
```

Comment: the error says,

Comment: External Tools- External Tool Failure = Revit Cannot run External application "Application NewRibbon01".

Answer (score 1):

This message indicates that you have installed an add-in manifest `*.addin` file in the Revit `AddIns` folder that refers to an external application `NewRibbon01` that cannot be loaded for some reason.

One possible reason is that it cannot be found.

For instance, the add-in .NET DLL assembly file may not be located in the same `AddIns` folder, or an invalid path to the add-in DLL may have been specified.

Please read and follow the basic information about [Revit add-in integration](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2022/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_html) in the Revit developers guide. It explains in full how to set up your add-in manifest correctly.

The previous link refers to the Revit 2022 developer guide. The same information applies to Revit 2020 as well: [Revit 2020 add-in integration](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2020/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Add_In_Integration_html)

The easiest way to get to grips with the fundamentals of Revit add-in installation, framework architecture and more advanced usage is to work through the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2). That will answer this question of yours in full and innumerable others as well.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, Last night I ended up starting over using the 2019 template and it worked because it was generating the .dll file that the 202o addinn template wasn't creating. I just need to remember to check and make sure when using the templates and I hit the Build feature, that it generates a dll file. is there a way to just add a .dll file to existing project if there is not one being created? like the problem I was having yesterday, I noticed that the project folder had no .dll file. that would be good if we could add one similar to the way we add a Class file.

Comment: another question I had was for the command, my ribbon button has been added and works fine using your addinn template. but I want my command to open and external file, like a hyperlink to an excel file. can this be done?

Comment: To open a file in .NET, you can use the File.Open method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=net-5.0

Comment: I sent you the file in an email, because its to hard to explain.

Comment: I think an explanation is required. No question, no answer.

Comment: my new error is: Revit cannot run the external application "Application NewRibbon02". Contact the provider for assistance. Information they provided to Revit about their identity: James Simpson, https://bimsquared.com.

Comment: Show Details: System.TypeLoadException- "Could not load type 'NewRibbon02.Command' from assembly 'NewRibbon02, Version=2019.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=null'.

Comment: maybe if I change the Version to 2021.1.0.0? because that's the version I am using? let me know, thanks

Comment: Okay, I worked out that error. but I want to replace my Trans,Try, return method to open a form1, I created.

Comment: using (Transaction Trans = new Transaction(doc))
            {
                //starts the transcation
                Trans.Start("Temp Trans");
                {

Comment: Reference eref = uidoc.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Select an object");
              //create a quick prompt
                        TaskDialog ts = new TaskDialog("Test Dialogue");
                        //tell it to show the selected elements name
                        ts.MainContent = doc.GetElement(eref).Name;
                        //display the dialog
                        ts.Show();
                        //commit the changes
                        Trans.Commit();
                        //return success
                        return Result.Succeeded;

Comment: I changed to this:  // This sample assumes that you have a folder named "c:\temp" on your computer.
        string filePath = @"K:\\Support\00_DETAIL LIBRARY\CSI_Masterformat\masterformat-2016.pdf";

        // Delete the file if it exists.
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }

        // Create the file.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath))
  
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);

Comment: I have a Command.cs, but when I run the Build command it ha these 3 errors that I cannot get rid of. 

CS0161 which is my line 21 = public Result Execute( 

CS1513 } expected which is line 56 at the very end of my code = }

Comment: not all code paths return a value -- read all about it here and elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-compiler-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value

Comment: Jeremy, I tried this but it has one error. how can I fix it?

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1729 'Form1' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments NewRibbon02

Comment: Example of my Code:

namespace NewRibbon02.Command
{
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class Command : IExternalCommand
{
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
{
Form1 wf = new Form1(commandData);

wf.ShowDialog();
wf.Close();

return Result.Succeeded;
}
}
}