# while loop with a boolean variable in an int method

Tags: c#

I have written two methods and added an infinite while loop in the method.

- The first method

```
    public static int GetNumber()
        {
            bool isCountinue = true;
            while (isCountinue)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter an integer number: ");
                string value = Console.ReadLine();
                bool isInteger = int.TryParse(value, out int number);
                if (isInteger)
                {
                    return number;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your input is not an integer number!");
                    isCountinue = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

- The second method

```
public static int GetNumber()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter an integer number: ");
            string value = Console.ReadLine();
            bool isInteger = int.TryParse(value, out int number);
            if (isInteger)
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input is not an integer number!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have gotten an error for the first method. Because it is missing the return value in the first method. I am confused why the second method is correct, and the first method is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# compiler error: "not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197410/c-sharp-compiler-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: What do you expect to happen when your input is not an integer? You're setting `isCountinue` to `false`, which means the loop will end... and there's no code after the ending `}` for the loop. In this case, it's possible to reach the end of the method without seeing a `return` with a value.

Comment: Because if isContinue = false program exit from loop and don't return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two methods do two slightly different things, which causes the problem:

**Version 1:**

When `isCountinue` is set to `false`, the `while` loop will stop running. Control will then pass to the next line after the loop, which is the `}` denoting the end of the method.

There is no `return` statement after the end of the loop. That makes the method invalid because it's required to return an `int`, but in that situation it has nothing to return.

**Version 2:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue says

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing iteration statement in which it appears

This means that when `continue` is executed, the `while` loop will run again.

Therefore the only possible exit from the loop - and more importantly, the whole method, is via the `return number;` line.

That's why the second version of the method compiles, but the first does not. In a non-void method, you must ensure that there is no path to the end of the method which does not involve a `return` statement.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely